# How to get a list of Posts and Reels using facebook graph API for my Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am using this endpoint to get a list of latest feed posts for my page:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/${facebookId}/feed?access_token=${access_token}&limit=20`

Apparently this works and returns the latest 20 posts published in the page's feed **(including reels)**, but there's no way to differentiate whether a video in the api result is a reels or just a normal video post, there's no field mentioned in the [Facebook Post Documentation's field list](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/#fields) that can identify my concern.

I know there's a specific endpoint for getting a list of reels similar to feeds endpoint:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/${facebookId}/video_reels?access_token=${access_token}`

But the issue with using this endpoint is that when I merge both of the above api results I will have duplicate posts, meaning video reels will be returned in both results.

Am I missing something or Is there any workaround for this?

I just want to achieve creating something similar to facebook profile page, where it shows both feed posts and reels together.

Comment: I don't see any filters mentioned in the documentation for the `feed` endpoint - so I suppose your left with the option to compare videos ids between what /feed and /video_reels return, if there is really nothing else in the data structure returned by /feed that would allow you to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 0):

Meta is not allowing posts and video reels to be retrieved in a single REST call.

Comment: link to official source to back up claim?